# Firebase-functions uploads entire project folder, not just the build folder

Tags: firebase, deployment, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a Next.js project with the production build files created in the .next folder.
The .next folder is located at the root of the project.

Everything deploys fine, logging process.env... shows it's the production environment.
Yet, when I deploy these are the logs I get:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged D:\Projects\other\project-parent-folder (6.48 MB) for uploading
+  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[parent-folder]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[parent-folder]: found 1 files in out
+  hosting[parent-folder]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function nextSsrServer(us-central1)...
+  functions[nextSsrServer(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
Function URL (nextSsrServer(us-central1)): https://us-central1-parent-folder-x.cloudfunctions.net/nextSsrServer
i functions: cleaning up build files...
i  hosting[parent-folder]: finalizing version...
+  hosting[parent-folder]: version finalized
i  hosting[parent-folder]: releasing new version...
+  hosting[parent-folder]: release complete

+  Deploy complete!
```

Regarding these specific lines:

```
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged D:\Projects\other\project-parent-folder (6.48 MB) for uploading
+  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
```

Does that mean the entire parent folder is uploaded by Functions? Is that normal? Doesn't Functions need just the production build?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure and also `firebase.json` ?

Comment: When you initialized FIrebase functions, it must have created a `functions` directory containing src code of functions only right? And the `source: "functions"` in config would have deployed that directory only. Can you specify how you generated this dir structure?

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me realize all I need to do is either restructure and reconfig, or, simply to add to the ignore list whatever I want it to ignore, that's all.